# script doesn't start on boot with init

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 345 99 01
# description: some startup script
### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides: weblogic
    # Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
    # Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
    # Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
    # Short-Description: start and stop OurDB
    # Description: OurDB is a very fast and reliable database
    #        engine used for illustrating init scripts
    ### END INIT INFO
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/function
service=startWebLogic.sh
user=*******
password=******
dbschemaname=******
hostname=*******
port=********
weblogic_start()
{
pgrep -f startWebLogic.sh > /dev/null
                if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "exit" |  sqlplus -L "$user/$password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=$hostname)(Port=$port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$dbschemaname)))" |  grep "Connected to" > /dev/null
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        /home/usr/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/bin/startWebLogic.sh &

                        else

                        echo "WARNING! No connection to the Oracle Server" | mail -s OracleServerDown monitoring@accedia.com

                        fi
                else

                echo "WARNING! Running WebLogic service was found!" | mail -s "Service Already Running" monitoring@example.com
                fi
}
weblogic_stop()
{
               pgrep -f startWebLogic.sh > /dev/null
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
                        /home/usr/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/Econt/bin/stopWebLogic.sh &  pid=$! ; sleep 5m; pkill -TERM -P $pid
                        ps -ef| grep $pid
                        if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
                        pkill -TERM -P $pid
                        fi

                        pid=`ps -ejH|grep "startWebLogic" | grep -iv "grep" | awk '{print $1}'`
                        pkill -TERM -P $pid


                else
                        echo "WARNING! No running WebLogic service was found" | mail -s "WebLogic Not Found" monitoring@example.com
                fi
}
case $1 in
    start)
            weblogic_start
        ;;
    stop)
            weblogic_stop
        ;;
    *) echo "Invalid input"

        ;;
esac
```

I've put it properly in init.d and stuff, chmod-ed it properly , put it in rc.local and yet again it doesn't want to start on boot, though if i run it manually , passing an argument to it ,e.g. "service weblogic start" it works fine , both as root and not. Anyone has any suggestions why is it acting like this and is there any solution to it ?

Comment: What **is** happening at boot? Is it trying to start and failing? How are you running it in `rc.local`? (Is there a reason you have it in `rc.local` instead of just letting the normal service init system handle starting it (via links in the appropriate `rc.X` directories, or whatever)?

Comment: It was like last resort with the rc.local.I've tried the normal way , nothing happened,  I have added a line in the beginning to make a .log file so i see if it even tries to start and it doesn't even try to do so.

Comment: What does that line look like? What does the line in `rc.local` running it look like? Are you logging standard output and standard error from the line in `rc.local`? Do other things in `rc.local` start correctly?

Comment: I've put a simple execution line withint the rc.local file /path/to/file start , but i've missed the sh before the command and it might have caused a problem , since rc.local doesn't tolerate any errors in commands.I am not logging the output and stderr and also do not have any other commands in rc.local , it is a newly created machine.

Comment: What distribution is this? Do you currently have the service starting links/etc. in place (other than the `rc.local` attempt)?

Comment: does your script get called at boot? have you *verified* that it isn't get called?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6.6. I have the links in 2,3,4,5 for start. I did it as any other time it just doesnt execute this time ... I don't know what is wrong ... was wondering if it wasn't a problem with the script itself , because everything else that is in init.d is working fine just that script isn't.Permissions are as follows : -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2558 May 15 14:55 weblogic

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I am not entirely sure what you are asking but I don't think it even tries to start it up.

Comment: put some debugging, e.g. in the second line `>/tmp/yahoooooo`. that's what I mean by *verified*.

Comment: I have line as follows and it is the first one to be executed : touch /tmp/weblogic but it isn't getting created.

Comment: you've verified this in 40 sec?

Comment: the line has been there for the past 6 hours , I have mentioned it earlier just didn't get your question right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put it in `init.d` and `rc.local` both places. One is enough.

You may try this after you put it in `init.d`:

For Debian based OS:

```
 sudo update-rc.d script_name defaults
```

For CentOS:

```
chkconfig --add myscript
```

Comment: sudo: update-rc.d: command not found
 That is the output i get from running the command you've given :/

Comment: which OS are you running..?

Comment: I am currently using CentOS 6.6 in Azure

Comment: weblogic        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
that's the output i get from chkconfig --list

Comment: Nothing again ... I have tried like every possible option i've found in the 1st 10 pages of Google searches for like 15 different things

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, the problem was with the priorites , I have changed the chkconfig options to 345 98 10 from 345 99 01.